# message-driven-destination in ejb-jar.xml for JBoss7

Tags: ejb, message-driven-bean, jboss7.x

So I am working on migration to JBoss7 ... Know I am encountering bunch of problems related to my XML (as expected). First was the

```
<acknowledge-mode>Auto-acknowledge</acknowledge-mode>
```

which was resolved from this [thread](http://community.jboss.org/message/639338?tstart=0.)

Now I am getting:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[39,10]
Message: Unexpected element 'message-driven-destination' encountered
        at org.jboss.metadat a.parser.util.MetaDataElementParser.unexpectedElement(MetaDataElementParser.java:109)
```

This is due to my xml containing:

```
<message-driven-destination>
        <destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</destination-type>
        <subscription-durability>Durable</subscription-durability>
</message-driven-destination>
```

But I cant figure out how should I properly set up the destination-type.

The full ejb-jar.xml that I have as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 2.0//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd">

<ejb-jar >

   <description><![CDATA[Message Driven Bean for processing subscription.]]></description>
   <display-name>EJB Bean</display-name>

   <enterprise-beans>

  <!-- Message Driven Beans -->
  <message-driven >
     <description><![CDATA[Bean for processing subscription.]]></description>
     <display-name>EJB Subscription Bean</display-name>
     <ejb-name>EJBSubscriptionBean</ejb-name>
     <ejb-class>com.package.bean.EJBSubscriptionBean</ejb-class>
     <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>

     <!-- To work with JBoss7 -->
     <!-- <acknowledge-mode>Auto-acknowledge</acknowledge-mode> -->

     <activation-config>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>Auto-acknowledge</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
     </activation-config>

    <!-- -->

     <message-driven-destination>
        <destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</destination-type>
        <subscription-durability>Durable</subscription-durability>
     </message-driven-destination>

  </message-driven>
   <message-driven >
     <description><![CDATA[Bean for processing refunds.]]></description>
     <display-name>E Refund Bean</display-name>
     <ejb-name>EJBRefundBean</ejb-name>
     <ejb-class>com.package.bean.EJBRefundBean</ejb-class>
     <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>

     <!-- To work with JBoss7 -->
     <!-- <acknowledge-mode>Auto-acknowledge</acknowledge-mode> -->

     <activation-config>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>Auto-acknowledge</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
     </activation-config>


     <message-driven-destination>
        <destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</destination-type>
        <subscription-durability>Durable</subscription-durability>
     </message-driven-destination>


  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed the ejb-jar.xml entirely to just:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0"?-->  
<ejb-jar version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">  
  <interceptors>  
    <interceptor>  
      <interceptor-class>com.package.bean.EJBSubscriptionBean</interceptor-class>  
    </interceptor>  
    <interceptor>  
      <interceptor-class>com.package.bean.EJBRefundBean</interceptor-class>  
    </interceptor>  
  </interceptors>  

  <assembly-descriptor>  
    <interceptor-binding>  
      <ejb-name>EJBSubscriptionBean</ejb-name>  
      <interceptor-class>com.package.bean.EJBSubscriptionBean</interceptor-class>  
    </interceptor-binding>  
    <interceptor-binding>  
      <ejb-name>EJBRefundBean</ejb-name>  
      <interceptor-class>com.package.bean.EJBRefundBean</interceptor-class>  
    </interceptor-binding>  
  </assembly-descriptor>  
</ejb-jar>
```

and add the settings through Annotations on the Beans themselves:

```
    //JBoss 7 / JDK 6  / EJB3 Annotations
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = { 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"), 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),  
      //  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/TEST_QUEUE"),  
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable")  })
```

Comment: "Durable" doesn't make sense in a queue. It is used only for topic subscriptions as queues may have many listeners and the queue doesn't care who received it, but only that it was received by a listener. With topics, all listeners must receive the message, thus the durability option.

Answer (score 3):

'message-driven-destination' is not supported in EJB 2.1 or above.
    This issue will be resolved by replacing  tag by

```
<message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
            <activation-config>
                 <activation-config-property>
                      <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
                      <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
                 </activation-config-property>
                 <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>java:/queue/CacheQueue</activation-config-property-value>
                 </activation-config-property>
            </activation-config>
```